# Bug when attempting to time my JavaScript functions

Tags: javascript, debugging, time

I was given the challenge which is essentially: given an array of numbers as input, find the greatest difference between any two numbers, given that j < i, and input[i] > input[j].

I wrote two solutions, one a brute-force double nested loop and the other my attempt at optimizing it. They are as follows:

```
// Brute Force Method
function findGreatestDiffV1(nums) {
  let start = new Date().getTime();
  let greatestDiff = 0;
  for (let i = 1; i < nums.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < i; j++) {
      let diff = nums[i] - nums[j];
      if (diff > greatestDiff) greatestDiff = diff;
    }
  }
  console.log(((new Date().getTime() - start) / 1000.0) + " Seconds");
  return greatestDiff;
}

// Optimized method
function findGreatestDiffV2(nums) {
  let start = new Date().getTime();
  let smallestNum = nums[0];
  let greatestDiff = 0;
  for (let i = 1; i < nums.length; i++) {
    if (nums[i] < smallestNum) smallestNum = nums[i];
    if ((nums[i] - smallestNum) < greatestDiff) continue;
    for (let j = 0; j < i; j++) {
      let diff = nums[i] - nums[j];
      if (diff > greatestDiff) greatestDiff = diff;
    }
  }
  console.log(((new Date().getTime() - start) / 1000.0) + " Seconds");
  return greatestDiff;
}
```

These work fine, and output both the correct results as well as the expected run-times, i.e. significantly lower for V2 for larger datasets.

I then modified them to return only the run-times:

```
function findGreatestDiffV1Time(nums) {
  let start = new Date().getTime();
  let greatestDiff = 0;
  for (let i = 1; i < nums.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < i; j++) {
      let diff = nums[i] - nums[j];
      if (diff > greatestDiff) greatestDiff = diff;
    }
  }
  return ((new Date().getTime() - start) / 1000.0);
}

function findGreatestDiffV2Time(nums) {
  let start = new Date().getTime();
  let smallestNum = nums[0];
  let greatestDiff = 0;
  for (let i = 1; i < nums.length; i++) {
    if (nums[i] < smallestNum) smallestNum = nums[i];
    if ((nums[i] - smallestNum) < greatestDiff) continue;
    for (let j = 0; j < i; j++) {
      let diff = nums[i] - nums[j];
      if (diff > greatestDiff) greatestDiff = diff;
    }
  }
  return ((new Date().getTime() - start) / 1000.0);
}
```

I created this helper function, which generates inputs of length `numOfDiffs` and of greatest individual number `maxDiff`:

```
function generateDiffs(numOfDiffs, maxDiff) {
  let diffs = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < numOfDiffs; i++) {
    diffs.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * maxDiff));
  }
  return diffs;
}
```

However, this is the point where things are bugging out and I cannot figure out why.

When using the versions which only return the run-time, regardless of the size of the input, I'm getting a time of 0 for V1. V2 is returning the correct time for any size set, but V1 continues to escape almost immediately and return 0.

The most likely issue is that I have an obvious bug somewhere, but I'm wondering if it might be some misunderstanding of how JavaScript performs some function, or even scope bleed somewhere. But regardless, I can't locate it and it's driving me crazy.

Comment: I suspect the Javascript compiler has noticed that you never use any of the variables after the loop, so it optimizes the entire loop away.

Comment: I'm not sure why this doesn't happen for V2, maybe the loops are a little too complex for it to analyze.

Comment: Try changing them to return an object containing the greatest diff and the time.

Comment: You can use `performance.now` for timings.

Comment: Very interesting. Does it do that no matter where you run it? I cannot reproduce in any of my browsers: https://jsfiddle.net/b0dm98ds/

Comment: I've only tried it in Chrome, admittedly. And I suspect you may be right @Barmar: because I'm not doing anything with the actual variable, Chrome may be optimizing it and just skipping the loop entirely. Sneaky Chrome! Let me try that and we'll see.

Comment: Barmar, you're absolutely right. That was the issue. If you want to post your comment as an answer, I'll mark it as correct; otherwise I'll answer my own question in ~30 minutes or so. :)

Answer (score 0):

So, @Barmar was the man here. Chrome absolutely was attempting to optimize my code by skipping everything it saw was never being returned by the function. Once I changed my return value to

```
return [((new Date().getTime() - start) / 1000.0), greatestDiff];
```

I began getting the expected results.

And it is definitely interesting that I wasn't getting this for V2; as Barmar said, it's likely that the more complex instructions were causing Chrome to err on the side of caution.

Also, for the record, here was the function I wrote to calculate the run-times.

```
function runTimes(numOfDiffs, maxDiff) {
  let runTimeDiffs = generateDiffs(numOfDiffs, maxDiff)
  let timesV1 = 0;
  let timesV2 = 0;
  for (let x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
    timesV1 += findGreatestDiffV1Time(runTimeDiffs)[0];
    timesV2 += findGreatestDiffV2Time(runTimeDiffs)[0];
  }
  console.log(`V1 times for numOfDiffs = ${numOfDiffs} and maxDiff = ${maxDiff} was: ${timesV1 / 10} seconds.`)
  console.log(`V2 times for numOfDiffs = ${numOfDiffs} and maxDiff = ${maxDiff} was: ${timesV2 / 10} seconds.`)
}
```

As for @gcampbell's suggestion of using performance.now, I'll look into that; I wasn't familiar with that functionality. Good to know these things :)